# What TBB changes require to enable compression?

Tags: dxa, 2013-sp1, dxa-1.7, publishingfailed

We are using DXA 1.7 .NET application. Seems the page publishing is failing because of the size of the page and component attached, and I noticed in Template Builder that "compression-enabled" is selected as NO. How can we make this field as YES, and will the compression help in page publishing?

[image: ange]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Compress output` TBB. you can enable compression by setting the parameter CompressionEnabled to 'yes'.

I am not sure about the TBB location for DXA 1.7 but for `DXA 2.2` the location is "\100 Master\Building Blocks\Framework\Developer\Templates\DXA.Legacy".